# unable to read empty cells in excel file to 2d array

Tags: javascript, js-xlsx

The code is working fine except where the cells are empty, the empty cells are ignored.
I know there are

- solution 1 .Condition "if(h===undefined)continue;" in "xlsx.core.min.js" comment it out.
- Solution 2 . By passing Condition extra param while running this XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[name] , {blankCell : false}). add a condition on line no. 19150 "if(defval === undefined && blankCell) continue;" in file xlsx.js etc..

But I don't have "xlsx.core.min.js" file in my project, and I can't fine a line no. 19150 to add a codition for solution 2, and also I am not creating JSON object.

my code:

```
onChange = (event) => {
        let newRows = this.state.rows;
        let files = event.target.files, f = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            let newRowCt = this.state.rowCt;
            let newColCt = this.state.colCt;
            var data = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
            const sn = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sn];
            console.log(sheet["!ref"]);
            let row = 1;
            let col = 0;
            Object.keys(workbook.Sheets[sn]).map((cell) => {
                if (sheet[cell].w !== undefined) {
                    if (row !== parseInt(cell.slice(1), 10)) {
                        row++;
                        col = 0;
                        if (row >= newRowCt) {
                            newRows.push([]);
                            for (let k = 0; k < newColCt; k++) {
                                newRows[row].push("");
                            }
                            newRowCt++;
                            console.log(newColCt);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create excel.js file to determine your jobs in excel like read,write,pick columns etc. On my code example i did it under that path : "./lib/excel.js"
Then you can export those methods. It will be better usage.

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const read = filePath => {
  const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath);  //it reads all excel file
  const sheetnamelist = workbook.SheetNames; //it takes all sheet names

  return XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetnamelist[0]]); //it returns json from your first sheet 
};

module.exports = {
  read
};
```

Then on your app.js you can import excel.js file using this.

```
const excel = require('./lib/excel');
```

Call your method code below.

```
const xlsx = excel.read(yourExcelFilePath);
console.log(xlsx);
```

You will see your empty cells as `''` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Xlsx does not have any settings to display the first empty rows and Columns. but there is a small tweak which could make things work like miracle.

```
const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        const bstr: string = e.target.result;
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary',cellDates: true});
        const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        let x = ws['!ref'];
        let newref = this.replaceChar(x, 'A1', 0); //B1:K4
        ws['!ref'] = newref;
        this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, defval: '', blankrows: true }));
        
    };



replaceChar(origString, replaceChar, index) {
    let firstPart = origString.substr(0, index);
    let lastPart = origString.substr(index + 2);
      
    let newString = firstPart + replaceChar + lastPart;
    return newString;
}
```

Attaching an excel for reference

[image]