# sheetJs - no output for empty cell

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I am using sheetjs. The empty cell is not getting populated in the json object including the header. I need that information also if a column is not entered. Here is my code:

```
workbook.SheetNames.forEach((sheetName) => {
    let XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], {defval:""});
    console.log( JSON.stringify(XL_row_object ));
}
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658841/3099258 , if this helps your motive

Answer (score 7):

You can solved it with this part, at the begining, when you are including your SheetJS:

**`**const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json((ws),{defval:""});**`**

- **data** is just a const which holds conversion from sheet to json
- **ws** is the name of our sheets which we are using for conversion and manipulation
- **defval** presents empty cell values. In our case it is an empty string ("")

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I solved this problem with this:

`XLSX.readFile('file', {sheetStubs:true})`

Answer (score 0):

To extend the `sheetStubs` answer, `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` will ignore stubs so you should first convert them with a simple function:

```
function removeStubs(wb) {
  Object.values(wb.Sheets).forEach(ws => {
    Object.values(ws).filter(v => v.t === 'z').forEach(v => Object.assign(v,{t:'s',v:''}));
  });
  return wb;
}
```

then call
`removeStubs( XLSX.readFile('file', {sheetStubs:true}) )`