# SheetJS - Fail to recognize second column

Tags: vuejs3, sheetjs

i'm using sheetJs utils.sheet_to_json and i'm getting only one column data. I have a border case where the A column has 10k rows (A1 is column name) and B column only has column name (B1) with no other data in rows. I need to get an object {a1_prop: value, b1_prop: '' } but i'm getting {a1_prop: value}. I'm trying this [sheetJs - no output for empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673503/sheetjs-no-output-for-empty-cell) but can't seem to make it work.

I can solve this externally, adding a prop to each object, but i would like to make it work with the lib

Any tips?

update: read(data) reads the B1 cell
[(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KfTz.png)